# Mssql login fail ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433

Tags: sql-server, database, macos, docker, tcp

while trying to log in using this .. mssql -u sa -p mypassword .i get this error, **Error: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433**
I have installed sql server on docker using this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/java-mac tutorial and started it.
I am using mac os sierra. I have searched all over internet including stackoverflow for this but gotten no answer. The only answer i get is to enable tcp/ip using sql configuration manager, but mac os doesn't have a configuration manager so I can enable the tcp/ip. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found the solution .. the docker set the memory as 2GB while the MS SQL server requires 3.25GB... All i had to do was go to the Docker preferences and changed the memory to 4GB and it works :). I was using sql server on docker on Mac.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time tp post your own solution here.  I spent ages trying to figure this out.  My container was working previously even though it was set to 2GB.  However when I updated Docker version it stopped running.  So what I had to do in the end to get this working, was as you described set my memory to 4GB, and even though I clicked apply and restart.  I still had to restart my mac for it to take effect, then all was working as per expected. My Docker Version 17.03.0-ce-mac2 (15654), if anyone else runs into this problem

Comment: For me I am getting same error.. Also I did Docker preferences memory to 4GB and restarted machine... Still I am getting same error

Comment: 17.03.1-ce-mac5 Docker Version I have

Comment: @KannanKandasamy what memory does your mac require to run docker?

Comment: @ros  not able to understand your question, My mac has 16 gb ram and In docker preferences i setup 4gb... As per sql server vnext documentation they are mentioning only 3.25

Comment: Hey @KannanKandasamy, maybe your problem is the password strength. I was looking my logs and saw this error: ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols.

Comment: I faced a similar problem and got it resolved by following this answer. Thanks @ros. 
I would like to know the reason for such behavior.

Comment: I did the same, but its not helping. Not sure why getting "Error: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433"

Comment: This is the solution. Once i increase the size. I remove the container  and try running the container again using the previous command. Eg, docker run -d --name sql_server -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=root' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux

Answer (score 11):

I'm using docker to set up containers and then sql-cli to access SQL server. This is how I resolved that error which I got after providing `mssql -u sa -p mypassword`.

1. What I didn't realize at the beginning was a too simple password provided before with setting up a docker container:

```
docker run -d --name Homer -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=myPassw0rd' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

The Terminal doesn't say this and only after going to docker > Kitematic and checking the logs of the just created container I saw such a security warning. I deleted that container and created a container with a strong password.

2. Then I got the error after I've started a wrong container (so the connection failed because I was trying to provide the password for a different container). Since then, I prefer to use Kinematic to manage and access my containers. Before I type `mssql -u sa -p mypassword` in the Terminal and start to work, I just go to docker > Kinematic and Start my container.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the container exited due to an insecure mssql password.
Try reading the container logs.

Comment: For anymore who's tried everything and still can't get past this. In my case, it was because the password was too complex– it appears that passwords with punctuation throw this error.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I just needed to start the container.

`docker start {container_name}`

Comment: Most probably first you need to check the container is up and running. So in my case this solved the my issue. you can see all the containers using `docker container ls -a`

Answer (score 4):

In my case (I was following this tutorial https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/) the problem was the host address.

I was trying to connect to localhost and I got the ECONNREFUSED message but then I realized that I needed to use the local IP docker assigned to the container (it was something like 192.168.xxx.xxx), so:

mssql -s 192.168..... -o 1433  -u sa -p 'mypassword'

finally worded.

Comment: Same here... I had to use `docker-machine ip` to find out the IP assigned to the VM.

Comment: this answer needs to be on top

Answer (score 3):

I had the same, in my case I notice that the problem was the PORT, so:

1)Check if the container is running with

```
docker start "container_name"
```

2)Then, get the correct PORT with:

```
docker ps
```

3) Run it

```
mssql -s "PORT" -o 1433 -u sa -p "pwd"
```

Comment: how to identify the container name ? @A. Juarez

Comment: `docker container ls -a` to see all containers. you will see a table and its' last column is names column.

Comment: How would you specify the "PORT"? For example, I created the container using: -p 1002:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest. When I try to run it using mssql -s 1002 -o 1433 -u sa -p "myPassword" I get an error saying that it can't connect to the port.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this answer to complement [Krzysztof Tomasz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097416/114029).

I was following this guide: [How to Install SQL Server on a Mac](https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/)

Everything was going well but at the time of connecting to the container with this command:

```
mssql -u sa -p mypass1
```

I got:

> Error: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:1433

Then I opened Docker app, clicked the container and in the Logs menu I could see the following:

[image]

> 2020-02-05 16:26:45.71 spid20s ERROR: Unable to set system
>   administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does
>   not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is too
>   short. The password must be at least 8 characters..

The password I set had only 7 chars. :o)

Now this makes sense.

This is also documented @ Microsoft doc here:

[Quickstart: Run SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash)

---

Solved this problem by [removing the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) and launching it again...

As I only had one container I ran the following command:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Then launched sql server image again with a stronger password:

```
docker run -d --name sql_server_demo -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=MyPass11' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, and it was a RAM issue, HOWEVER... 4GB didn't do it for me, for some reason in my case I needed 6, then it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by updating the port from 1422 to 1433, I used Kitematic to implement this update.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have started the container in docker.

Command to start a container: `docker start container "containerName"`

and then try to connect mssql

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem too, after study the logs with two commands:

```
docker ps -a
```

then

```
docker logs 99373f58f2ff
```

I understood that problem is related to the password dose not to meet SQL Server password policy! That's is.